# Missing a href tag in Safari, Edge and IE, but not Firefox, datatables?

Tags: safari, datatables

I have a list of courses that links to instructor profiles, generated by PHP, and I'm using DataTables to sort and display.  In Firefox, the `<a href>` tag around the instructor name is there, just as I coded it in the PHP.  But when I view the same page in Microsoft Edge, IE or Safari, and I view the page source, there is no `<a>` tag there at all!

I can only guess that either
a) DataTables is stripping it for some reason?  OR
b) there is some minor error in the DOM and the browser is stripping out the tag?

The URL is: http://ota.iewwritingteacher.com/courses - Each place where it says "Instructor:" followed by a name, is supposed to be a link.

The PHP code is straightforward:

```
<p>Instructor: <a href="/teacher/<?php echo $teacherlink; ?>"><?php echo $event_meta['instructor']; ?></a></p>
```

Can anybody help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: I'm not seeing the `href` in any browser, including Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

In order to render a link from text, you need to do a little something different in Datatables.

```
$("#example").DataTable({
                "data": final_data,            
               "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "url",
                    "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
      return '<a href="'+data+'">SOMETHING</a>';
                }
                          ],
                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bunch of digging around, I realized that an OLD version of the page was being delivered by a caching plugin I did not install!  Endurance Page Cache was installed as an mu-plugin by HostMonster, and thus, had static copies of an old version of the page (before I added the link to the code).

Why certain browsers delivered the page to me correctly, not from that cache, and others did not, I still do not know.  But the problem is fixed now!